# Stop function from running on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, settimeout, each, onmouseover

I have created a function which loops through a set of divs and extracts the `data-hover` attribute. I am then storing these values in an array and looping through them, generating an image and then appending them to another div. I have added a `setTimeOut` function to delay the loading of these images and I am using css animations to create the effect that they are loading one by one.

This function only runs once and happens when I mouseover the parent div '`thumbnail-wrapper`'. Once they are loaded into the DOM I have created another function which fires on `mouseleave` and adds the class hidden to the rollover images.

I then have another function which fires on mouseover which effectively works the same as the first one but this time just adds the class '`fadeIn`' and dynamically add's a `z-index` value so they appear to load on top of each other.

This all works If a user keeps their mouse over on the '`thumbnail-wrapper`' as all the imgs are having the time to load. However, If you leave the div before the count has finished it adds the 'hidden' class to the parent div but depedning on what time your cursor left, it doesn't remove the class '`FadeIn`' or reset the `z-index` as the count is still happening.

Is there a way I can prevent the count from completing on the '`on.mouseover`' function If a user removes their cursor?

```
function rolloverImages() {

  $('.thumbnail-wrapper').one('mouseover', function() {

        var rollovers = $(this).find('.rolloverimages div');
        var time = 0;

        rollovers.each(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
              var datasrc = $(this).data('hover');
              var img = $('<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic">');
              var imgsrc = img.attr('src', datasrc);
              var parent = $(this).parent('.rolloverimages').parent('.thumbnail-wrapper').find('.rolloverloaded');
              imgsrc.appendTo(parent);
            }.bind(this), time);
            time += 200;
        });

        console.log("images loaded to DOM");
    });

    $('.thumbnail-wrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.rolloverloaded').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).find('.rolloverloaded img').removeClass('fadeIn').css({'z-index':'0'});;
    });

    $('.thumbnail-wrapper').on('mouseover', function() {

      var time = 0;

        if($(this).find('.rolloverloaded').hasClass('hidden')) {

          $(this).find('.rolloverloaded').removeClass('hidden');
          $(this).find('.rolloverloaded img').removeClass('fadeIn');

        var count = 1;

        $(this).find('img').each(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
            count++;
            $(this).addClass('fadeIn').css('z-index', count);
            }.bind(this), time);
            time += 200;
        });

      }
    });
```

This is the what ends up happening if the mouse leaves before the count finishes

```
    <div class="rolloverloaded hidden”>
    <img class="" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-4-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 0;">
<img class="" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-2-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 0;">
<img class="" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-1-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 0;">
<img class="" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-6-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 0;">
<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-7-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 7;">
<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-3-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 8;">
<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-8-360x259.jpg" style="z-index: 9;">
<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/blue-moon-creative-hamilton-self-storage-10-360x259.gif" style="z-index: 10;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function rolloverImages() {

  $('.thumbnail-wrapper').one('mouseover', function() {

        var rollovers = $(this).find('.rolloverimages div');
        var time = 0;
        var $e = $(this);
        $e.attr("data-persist",true);

        rollovers.each(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
              if ($e.attr("data-persist")) {
                  var datasrc = $(this).data('hover');
                  var img = $('<img class="fadeIn" id="dynamic">');
                  var imgsrc = img.attr('src', datasrc);
                  var parent = $(this).parent('.rolloverimages').parent('.thumbnail-wrapper').find('.rolloverloaded');
                  imgsrc.appendTo(parent);
              }
            }.bind(this), time);
            time += 200;
        });

        console.log("images loaded to DOM");
    });

    $('.thumbnail-wrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).attr("data-persist",false);
        $(this).find('.rolloverloaded').addClass('hidden');
        $(this).find('.rolloverloaded img').removeClass('fadeIn').css({'z-index':'0'});;
    });

    $('.thumbnail-wrapper').on('mouseover', function() {

      var time = 0;

            if($(this).find('.rolloverloaded').hasClass('hidden')) {

              $(this).find('.rolloverloaded').removeClass('hidden');
              $(this).find('.rolloverloaded img').removeClass('fadeIn');

             var count = 1;

        $(this).find('img').each(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("data-persist")) {
                count++;
                $(this).addClass('fadeIn').css('z-index', count);
            }
            }.bind(this), time);
            time += 200;
        });

      }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. However, I've tried your code and the problem still exists.

Comment: I basically need to stop the second mouseover function from running if the mouse leaves the div. Currently, If i leave the div the second mouseover function continues to run so It doesn't have chance to remove the class and z-index